# Visual Studio - How to set how many times a test is run

Tags: c#, selenium, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio Community 2015, is there a way to set the amount of times a test method is executed?

Right now I'm trying to test my script and look at my output for the test, but after the test finishes, after about 10 seconds, it will start to run again.  After about 23mins of waiting and 15 script executions later, it finally stops.  I looked online on how to do this, but I couldn't find anything.

The following is what I have set above the method (not allowed to post whats in the method.  There is nothing in the method that deals with iteration or loops anyways):

> [TestMethod] //<== This indicates that this is a test method and should show up in Test Explorer
>           [TestCategory("UI")] //<== This is a UI Test
>           //[TestCategory("Nightly")] //<== This is to be run nightly
>           [DeploymentItem("TestData.xls")] //<== Use the Excel spreadsheet for data
>           [DataSource("*******")] //

Comment: How is the second time run triggered?

Comment: That's the thing, I don't know how it's being triggered.  Doesn't matter if I right-click the method from Test Explorer or from where the method is located in the .cs file, it will always keep triggering another run.

Comment: Which test framework?  Please post your test code.

Comment: I'm using Selenium with C#.  And I don't think I can post the code I'm executing considering this information is for a client.  I'll post the code I have above the method though considering it doesn't give away too much information.  I'll update my question with more information right now.

Answer (score 0):

Once I removed [TestCategory("UI")] & [TestCategory("Nightly")], it solved my problem.